# Rewrite rule is applying to existing directories

Tags: apache

In my apache site configuration file, I have the following. The rewrite rule works fine, but the rule is applying to existing directories which my rewrite conditions were supposed to fix. Here is my rewrite script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ test.php?n=$1 [L]
```

So `example.com/username` works great and uses `test.php`, but also when I enter an existing sub-directory that has an `index.php` file in it, aka, `example.com/myDirectory/` still uses test.php. Any idea what's wrong with my script? Thanks.

Below is a rewrite log for request `myDirectory` which is an existing directory:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /myDirectory/
(1) pass through /myDirectory/
(3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/myDirectory/ -> myDirectory/
(3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$' to uri 'myDirectory/'
(3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/myDirectory/ -> myDirectory/
(3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'myDirectory/'
(2) [perdir /var/www/] rewrite 'myDirectory/' -> 'test.php?n=myDirectory'
(3) split uri=test.php?n=myDirectory -> uri=test.php, args=n=myDirectory
```

And here is the log for request `bananas` which is meant to use the rewrite (and does):

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /bananas
(1) pass through /bananas
(3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/bananas -> bananas
(3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$' to uri 'bananas'
(3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/bananas -> bananas
(3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'bananas'
(2) [perdir /var/www/] rewrite 'bananas' -> 'test.php?n=bananas'
(3) split uri=test.php?n=bananas -> uri=test.php, args=n=bananas
```

Comment: Step 1: enable logging of URL rewriting (with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`) and see exactly what's happening (and post the logs if they don't seem to immediately illuminate the problem).

Comment: @larsks Okay, added them. But I don't see anything that tips me off as to why it's ignoring existing directories...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I should've posted all my code. I had a second rewrite rule in there. So it looked like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ tag/index.php?t=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ test.php?n=$1 [L]
```

What I didn't know, is that you have to apply the RewriteCond before every rule. [I found that answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277365/htaccess-seems-to-be-ignoring-rewritecond)

So the correct way is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ tag/index.php?t=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ test.php?n=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have those directives inside a `<Directory>` block.  If I put those rules, verbatim, into my local Apache configuration:

```
<Directory "/srv/http">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ test.php?n=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

And make sure that `RewriteLogLevel` is `>=` 4:

```
RewriteLogLevel 4
```

I see the following in the logs if I request `/myDirectory`:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /myDirectory/
(1) pass through /myDirectory/
(3) [perdir /srv/http/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/myDirectory/ -> myDirectory/
(3) [perdir /srv/http/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'myDirectory/'
(4) [perdir /srv/http/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/myDirectory/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
(1) [perdir /srv/http/] pass through /srv/http/myDirectory/
```

Whereas if I request a directory that does *not* exist, I get something like:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /notmyDirectory/
(1) pass through /notmyDirectory/
(3) [perdir /srv/http/] add path info postfix: /srv/http/notmyDirectory -> /srv/http/notmyDirectory/
(3) [perdir /srv/http/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/http/notmyDirectory/ -> notmyDirectory/
(3) [perdir /srv/http/] applying pattern '^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$' to uri 'notmyDirectory/'
(4) [perdir /srv/http/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/notmyDirectory' pattern='!-d' => matched
(4) [perdir /srv/http/] RewriteCond: input='/srv/http/notmyDirectory' pattern='!-f' => matched
(2) [perdir /srv/http/] rewrite 'notmyDirectory/' -> 'test.php?n=notmyDirectory'
```

So the rules are doing exactly what you want.

Try cranking up the `RewriteLogLevel` to 4 (anything lower will not show `RewriteCond` processing).

Comment: Well, they are doing exactly what I want on *your* server. But still not mine. I set the `RewriteLogLevel` to 5, and oddly, my logs are still not showing any logs above level 3. I have the `RewriteLog` directive in the `<VirtualHost>` block, because it won't let me put it in the `<Directory>` block. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Sorry @larsks - I didn't paste all my code. I had an extra rule. Answer posted below. Thanks so much for your help.